# Find the first same capital letter in two arrays using C

Tags: c, pointers, null

I tried to run this code but get NULL returned, which part is wrong?
The correct output should be "THU" because 'D' is the fourth capital letter.

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *day(char* s1, char* s2) {
    char* week[] = {"MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"};
    int stop = 1;
    char ans = 0;

    while (*s1 && stop) {
        while (*s2) {
            if (*s1 == *s2 && *s1 >= 'A' && *s1 <= 'Z') {
                ans = *s1;
                stop = 0;
                break;
            }
            s2++;
        }
        s1++;
    }

    return week[ans - 'A'];
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", day("3485djDkxh4hhGE", "2984akDfkkkkggEdsb"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @rootkonda (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63259897/4386427) explains why the code didn't work. I'll address other issues and propose an alternative implementation.

Depending on the input, your code have illegal (aka undefined) behavior.

If the input is `"aI"` and `"bI"`, you will do:

```
return week['I' - 'A]
```

which is

```
return week[8];
```

So you access the array out of bounds.

A similar problem will happen in case the two strings doesn't have a common capital letter. Then you do:

```
return week[0 - 'A'];  // bad....
```

Your code should handle such cases without failing.

As the task is described the only valid captital letter are `'A', 'B', ..., 'G'`.

Your current code checks the content of `s2` for each letter in `s1`. This results in O(N^2) complexity, i.e. poor performance for long strings when the matching capital letter is near the end of `s1`.

Below is a proposal that first analyzes `s1` and generates a scoreboard for captital letters. Then it analyzes `s2` while using the scoreboard. The complexity is O(N).

```
char *day(char* s1, char* s2) 
{
    char* week[7] = {"MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"};

    int capitalLettersFound[7] = {0};  // Scoreboard for 'A' .. 'G'
    
    while (*s1) 
    {
        if (*s1 >= 'A' && *s1 <= 'G') 
        {
            // Update scoreboard
            capitalLettersFound[*s1 - 'A'] = 1;
        }
        ++s1;
    }
    
    while (*s2) 
    {
        if (*s2 >= 'A' && *s2 <= 'G' && capitalLettersFound[*s2 - 'A'] == 1) 
        {
            // Match found - return string
            return week[*s2 - 'A'];
        }
        ++s2;
    }

    // No match found
    return "No matching capital letters found";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you are running the inner loop for every character in s2 and then s2 ends. After that we have to reset s2 to the beginning again. Hence I stored it in temp and resetting to s2 when u start for every next character in s1. I tested this code and I see THU as output.

```
 char* day(char* s1, char* s2)
    {
    char* week[7] = {"MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"};
    int stop = 1;
    char ans = 0;
        char* temp = s2;
    while (*s1 && stop) {
        while(*s2) {
            if (*s1 == *s2 && *s1 >= 'A' && *s1 <= 'Z') {
                ans = *s1;
                stop = 0;
                break;
            }
            s2++;
            cout << *s2 <<endl;
        }
        s1++;
        s2=temp;
    }
    return week[ans - 'A'];
    }
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, there is a better approach to do this. You can improve the code by skipping inner loop iterations when *s1 is not an upper case letter.

Comment: That's true. Thanks!